# "ORDER BY FIELD" MySQL does not seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

long story short, my order by field does not seem to be working for my MySQL call.  I can't really find a pattern in the storage...

$theorder is set correctly as

```
, 'People-Wedding Photo', 'People-Kids', 'People-Male/Female', 'Architecture-Exterior', 'Architecture-Interior', 'Animal-Birds', 'Backgrounds'
```

And here is my code.  As you can see, I am looping through, doing my format converting....but I still get a wrong order... a RANDOM order....

Is there something I am missing?

```
$under_link_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(type), type FROM ".$prefix."ProFolio_work WHERE type != 'Backgrounds' ORDER BY FIELD(type" . $theorder .")");


    while($u_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($under_link_query)){
        $type = html_entity_decode($u_row['type']);

        $typeForm = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $type);
        ?>
           <a href="#" id="link_<? echo str_replace(' ', '_', $typeForm); ?>">
    <? echo ucfirst($type); ?></a>
            <?
```

Comment: What is the variable $theorder, and where is it set correctly? I am confused. Is the first bit the order you want it in? Why not do something like SELECT .... FROM ... ORDER BY type DESC or ASC depending on which way you want it?

Comment: The correct syntax, iirc, is `ORDER BY $fieldname`, which you should sanitize by default.  Also, the `ORDER BY` will sort based on that field...but according to the priority as set by the db. Numeric ordering is far more predictable than associative ordering. My recommendation is to take the data and manipulate it with php into the format you want to use.

Comment: Its known as "ORDER BY FIELD" where you can manually specify the order you want results to appear.  http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Handy_MySQL_-_ORDER_BY_FIELD.cfm

Comment: Does the order list [after the fieldname in FIELD(...)] contain every value in the field?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you have `type` twice in the Select list?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yep, all fields are accounted for.

Comment: @ypercube not sure, thats how I read it somewhere :P   I never said I knew what I was doing haha

Comment: @PaulHanak, can you show your database schema? It seems like you are `order by`ing on column `type` values?

Comment: Are you saying that the rows are not grouped together in the order you are specifying (that is, it should be all `People-Wedding Photo` together followed by all `People-Kids` together) and it's not? You're getting values of `type` outside the order you are specifying?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, that is correct good sir.  The order I am specifying is not the order that it is outputting. The database is composed of a photo gallery, each photo in the photo gallery has a "type" field which is the name of the CATEGORY. This mysql_query should display ALL categories only once (thats what the distinct part is for), in the sort order I specify.  It HAS worked before with my current, but when I went in and added a NEW category, it "broke", but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I can't make this go wrong, but I don't really have suitable data. It's possible that selecting `type` twice might be making a difference: if you want only distinct values from a single column, just select that column. [It's also apparent that some people don't get what `ORDER BY FIELD` is supposed to do]

Comment: heh, agreed.  I did try removing the second instance of type from the selection, and it yielded the same exact results.  :(   The column you are refering to could have 20 of the same named "types".  So this is why I am using distinct.  Out of 300 photos, there about 10 types (aka, categories), so by using distinct, I am pulling out ONLY distinct results instead of iterating and displaying 300 rows.  I am displaying the 10 rows, but the ORDER of those just ins't cooperating.

Comment: I also just found this: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-FIELD-function-in-ORDER-BY-clause-in-MySQL-1321.php  in which... the second example seems to do the same thing!!!!  he tried ordering by field, but as you can see in the output, that's NOT the order....

Comment: I think that site has just copied the wrong result table, it's a copy of the one above it. Which was the new category which broke yours? Was it the `Male/Female` with the slash? Or `Wedding Photo` with a space? Clutching at straws now, though. And the SO site is going to start objecting to the number of comments.

Comment: Well, no need, I FOUND THE PROBLEM! *sigh*  You look at something so many times and it blends together. 'Architecture-Exterior', 'Architecture-Interior'  SHOULD have been 'Architecture Exterior' and 'Architecture Interior'.  Yes, spaces instead of dashes.  I changed it and there we have it! All pretty.  I appreciate the help Andrew.  Without your patience and help, I wouldn't have probably walked away and not figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

@Malovich is onto the answer, basically you should use:

```
ORDER BY $theorder
```

But keep in mind that default ordering is ascending, and ordering happens sequentially.  I've noted that your variable `$theorder` is set to a string that starts with a comma, which is pretty much your issue.

Make sure `$theorder` doesn't start with a comma, and then try to just order on one row.  if that works, keep adding more.

=============== EDIT =================

Apologies, you're trying to sub-sort a field.  Missed that part, so here's what's going on:

You need to provide all fields to sort on, or MySQL will sort each of the fields you haven't provided first, then it will sort on the fields you have provided.  If you want, you can provide a sub-set of fields to order on, but you'll need to provide them in reverse order, then use the DESC notation like:

```
ORDER BY FIELD (field,'lastsort',middlesort','firstsort') desc
```

This shows your list in the following order:

```
firstsort items
middlesort items
lastsort items
<all other options, in reverse alphabetical order> items
```

The key part of this is you'll need to add all field values to sort on. (or use the workaround).

Comment: yes, $theorder is a string that starts with a comma. If you look at the syntax, when you use order by field, you have to SPECIFY the field... so, it equates to ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'Field Name 1', 'Field Name 2') etc..   But you are saying you can specify the MANUAL order of something by saying "Order By 'Field Name 1','Field Name 2'" etc... it doesnt seem to be working for me... i keep getting syntax errors...

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD` changes the order sequence of values within that field. A trivial example is sorting `id` codes backwards: `ORDER BY FIELD(id,'E','D','C','B','A')`. It doesn't specify multiple fields to sort by.

Comment: In MySQL order by supports multiple order columns given a table that looks like:

id | name1 | name2 | name3

ORDER BY id DESC, name1, name3, name2

will sort by id (from greatest to lowest because of the DESC (descending)), then by name1, then by name3 then by name2.  Given that id is probably unique, the next 3 columns will be ignored.  But if you sort using:

ORDER BY name1 desc, name2

Anytime the value in name1 is duplicated, it will sub-sort that data by name2.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html